# How to create the other admin account in magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to create the other Admin account in Magento 2.

How to give the customer account to Admin right?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create New Admin User

Step 1: Configure User Information 
Step 2: Determine User Role

**Step 1: Configure User Information**

On the Admin panel, click `system`.  In the `permission` section, select `add new user`.

**Step 2: Determine User Role**

In the panel on the left, choose `user role` . The grid lists all the existing roles. Initially, the only role available is Administrators.

Answer (score 0):

Procedure
The procedure involves two steps: adding the user role, then adding the user.
1: Add user role
If you wish to grant complete admin access to the user, you may skip to 2: Add user instead of creating a specific role. This will, however, involve granting the new user complete admin access and therefore access to all of your store's most critical areas. Use care when assigning the Administrator role.
Log in to your Magento Dashboard.
On the left, click System > User Roles (Figure 1).

Figure 1. Magento Dashboard; System > User Roles.
Click Add New Role (Figure 2).

Figure 2. Roles page; Add New Role button.
On the New Role page, enter the desired name in the Role Name field and your current password in the Current Admin Password field (Figure 3).

Figure 3. New Role page; Role Name and Current Admin Password fields.
On the left, click Role Resources (Figure 4).

Figure 4. New Role Page; Role Resources selection.

Attention: In Step 6, you will choose which permissions to assign to the new role. If you are unsure, consult with your developer. As always, take care when assigning permissions, as many grant secure access to critical areas of your store.
From the Resource Access drop-down list, select Custom if not already selected. Assign permissions as desired.

Figure 5. Resource Access drop-down list; Custom selection with associated check boxes.
Click Save Role (Figure 6).

Figure 6. Save Role button.
2: Add user
On the left, click System > All Users (Figure 7).

Figure 7. System > All Users.
Click Add New User (Figure 8).

Figure 8. Add New User button.
On the New User page, fill all fields in the Account Information and Current User Identity Verification sections (Figure 9).

Figure 9. New User page and relevant fields.
In the User Information section, click User Role (Figure 10).

Figure 10. User Information section; User Role selection.

Attention: In Step 5 below, if you assign the default Administrators role instead of a custom role, that user will have complete access to all of your store's most critical areas. Use care when assigning this role.
In the Assigned column, select the check box corresponding to the role you created in the “1: Add user role” section (Figure 11).  If you want to grant complete admin access, select the Administrators check box.

Figure 11. Sample new_role check box.
Click Save User. If the procedure was successful, you will now see the admin user represented in User list on the User page (Figure 12).

Figure 12. Newly created sample user on User Page.